# Getting build failed for DriverLicenseParser integrate scanner

Tags: ios, iphone

When I build the project its give me:

> build failed for ld: library not found for -lDriverLicenseParser
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I want to integrate driving licence scanner I am going with below two links:

1. http://idscan.net/wp/solutions/enterprise/id-parsing-sdk/
2. http://idscan.net/wp/downloads/

But I haven't any solution. I have one source code also but error occurs like this.

libDriverLicenseParser.a

> ld: library not found for -lDriverLicenseParser clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

[image]

If any solution please give me. I'm so confused this type of error.

Comment: libDriverLicenseParser.a missing in project..

Comment: yes i have also a source code but..libDriverLicenseParser.a is missing..

Comment: // for using tableview cell for row at indexpat NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %ld %ld",(long)indexPath.row,(long)indexPath.section];

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication )application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary )launchOptions
{
    RootViewController * viewcontroller = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewcontroller];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

Comment: app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];